# Agregar un nuevo objeto a un JSON en Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

Como agrego nuevos datos dentro mi object películas:

```
let pelicula = {
    "film": {
        "titulo": "Rapidos y furiosos 100", 
        "fecha": "2020", 
        "duracion": "2"
    }
}
```

como le hago para agregar otro film que quede así:

```
let pelicula = {
    film: {
        titulo: "Rapidos y furiosos 100",
        fecha: "2020",
        duracion: "2"
    },
    {
        titulo: "Harry Potter",
        fecha: "2010",
        duracion: "3"
    }
}
```

Ósea como crear otra instancia de film con esos atributos para cada nueva película, no sé si escribí bien el segundo código, solo es un ejemplo.
Pienso que si accedo al key film voy a sobrescribir la película anterior.

Comment: Tal y como lo quieres no es un objeto válido (prueba a ponerlo tal cual en la consola de tu navegador y verás que te dice que la llave de apertura del segundo valor que quieres introducir en la propiedad `film` es inesperada). Lo que deberías hacer es que `film` sea un array de objetos

Comment: Claro, pero como hacerlo dinámico, cada vez que llame a una función se agregue un nuevo elemento en el array(film)

Answer (score 2):

Tal y como lo quieres no es un objeto válido (prueba a ponerlo tal cual en la consola de tu navegador y verás que te dice que la llave de apertura del segundo valor que quieres introducir en la propiedad film es inesperada). Lo que deberías hacer es que film sea un `array` de objetos. Así podrías directamente hacer un `push` de tu nuevo objeto en tu `array` `film` (o ya de paso renombrarlo a `films` para que quede más coherente)

```js
let pelicula = {
  films: [{
    titulo: "Rapidos y furiosos 100",
    fecha: "2020",
    duracion: "2"
  }] 
};

function addFilm(films, film){
  films.push(film);
}

console.log(pelicula.films);

addFilm(pelicula.films,{
    titulo: "Harry Potter",
    fecha: "2010",
    duracion: "3"
  });
  
console.log(pelicula.films);
```